# How do I force a WP_Image_Editor.resize to stretch my image if needed?

Tags: php, wordpress, imagemagick, imagick

When I call the function `WP_Image_Editor->resize(...)` and the image's height is too small, it ignores the height I pass in. For example:

```
//This image is 300 x 225
$image = wp_get_image_editor( "/var/www/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/test.jpg" );

//I tell it to resize to 290 x 290
$image->resize( 290, 290 ); //Passing "true" to crop doesn't help)

//It saves, but as 290 x 225!
$image->save( "/var/www/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/test-22.jpg" );
```

How do I make it stretch to the proper size and ratio?

**EDIT Here is what's returned by each function call above:**

```
//var_dump of wp_get_image_editor( $myImagePath );
object(WP_Image_Editor_Imagick)#109 (6) {
    ["image":protected]=>
    object(Imagick)#108 (0) {
    }
    ["file":protected]=>
    string(65) "/var/www/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/test.jpg"
    ["size":protected]=>
    array(2) {
        ["width"]=>
        int(300)
        ["height"]=>
        int(225)
    }
    ["mime_type":protected]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["default_mime_type":protected]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["quality":protected]=>
    int(90)
}

//var_dump of $image->resize( 290, 290 );
bool(true)

//var_dump of $image->save( "/var/www/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/test-22.jpg" );
array(5) {
    ["path"]=>
    string(68) "/var/www/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/test-22.jpg"
    ["file"]=>
    string(11) "test-22.jpg"
    ["width"]=>
    int(294)
    ["height"]=>
    int(225)
    ["mime-type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a filename into your `$image->save();` call.

If you refer to the docs [1] you can see they pass in a new filename.

[1] http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_image_editor

Comment: What about if you try your command and then check that it's not returning a WP_Error [1]. Like in the docs above. [1] http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error

Comment: I did check for the error and it says everything is fine. There's no error.

Comment: If this was me, then I'd next check WP_DEBUG was on, see if any errors are being caused, or if it was a permissions error.

What if you var_dump the result of $image->save( 'new-file.jpg' );

Comment: I did all that. there are no errors. and when I dump the return value it shows everything like it should when there's no error. trust me, there is no error. I think it's a problem with imagemagick not scaling up when a certain setting is passed (which is done behind the scenes by WordPress)

Comment: What OS / environment are you developing in? Server error logs?

Comment: OS = CentOS 6 Server. I checked the logs and there are no errors. :(

Comment: Please see my updated post, I added the `var_dump` of every function call.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a built-in limit that comes from the `image_resize_dimensions` function (in wp-includes/media.php).

```php
// Stop if the destination size is larger than the original image dimensions.
```

There's a filter, though, called `image_resize_dimensions` which you can use like so:

```php
add_filter( 'image_resize_dimensions', function( $output, $orig_w, $orig_h, $dest_w, $dest_h, $crop ) {
    return array( 0, 0, 0, 0, $dest_w, $dest_h, $orig_w, $orig_h );
}, 10, 6 );
```

The above will ignore aspect ratios and whatnot and just return what you asked for and results in stretched images. Be careful.